# Appium shows only a skeleton source with XCUIElementTypeOther for a ReactNative app

Tags: react-native, appium, react-native-ios, webdriver-io, appium-ios

Did anyone ever have an issue with appium, that when you want it to print the source of your iOS (ReactNative) app, it will only show you a skeleton with many `XCUIElementTypeOther` but no tags/names/IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can add test id for iOS with `testID` prop

```
<View testID="your-test-id-here" />
```